Tamaron 150-500 A011 lens auto focus issue
I bought the Tamaron 150-600 A011 lens 7 years ago. As I was focused on my work, the lens was being used rarely. I was having VR issues which are not yet resolved due to motor problems. I also found that the autofocus is having a problem even though the focus button is maintained on autofocus mode for lens and camera D7200. I need to move the focus ring manually which is not always giving me the best results.
Can I resolve the VR issues out of warranty? What could be the cost?
Thanks and regards
Rahul

Just checking - we're talking about the Tamron SP 150-600mm f/5-6.3 Di VC USD (I'm assuming "Tamaron" is a typo or something, though it's not unknown for people to sell things under a "sounds like" name of a known manufacturer). What autofocus problems are you having? Long telephoto lenses are particularly prone to "hunt" for focus.

Who is responsible for Tamron service in your country? Have you contacted them? That would seem like the sensible thing to do.

Sorry for typos. Whenever I try to press focus button, the lens doesn’t try to focus and I am forced to manually move the focus ring even though body and lens has auto focus on
